# Sending alert through GPS

Tags: android, gps, alert

I am creating an application including GPS services . I have a query that whether is it possible to send alert ring tones from one android device to another through GPS only.

Comment: You can't , GPS only concern with Location API. for sending any data over network you require `GPRS`, `3G` or `Wifi`

Comment: @Kedarnath thanks for your answer. Can you please further tell me :- I have a list of registered drivers . How can I find the position of their cars using GPS. What prerequisites I will be needing  for this. (Please tell me if this is not clear to you.)

Comment: Its simple, you need to create an application that periodically sends its GPS ( lat-lon ) information to remote server. And from that remote server you can access the information for a particular driver.